# How do you explicitly show rows which have count(*) equal to 0

Tags: sql, database, db2

The query I'm running in DB2

```
select  yrb_customer.name, 
        yrb_customer.city, 
        CASE count(*) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE count(*) END as #UniClubs 
from  yrb_member, yrb_customer 
where yrb_member.cid = yrb_customer.cid and yrb_member.club like '%Club%' 
group by yrb_customer.name, yrb_customer.city  order by count(*)
```

Shows me people which are part of clubs which has the word 'Club' in it, and it shows how many such clubs they are part of (`#UniClubs`) along with their name and City. However for students who are not part of such a club, I would still like for them to show up but just have 0 instead of them being hidden which is what's happening right now. I cannot get this functionality with `count(*)`. Can somebody shed some light? I can explain further if the above is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT yrb_customer.name, yrb_customer.city,
       COUNT(yrb_member.club) as clubCount
FROM yrb_customer
LEFT JOIN yrb_member
       ON yrb_member.cid = yrb_customer.cid
          AND yrb_member.club LIKE '%Club%
GROUP BY yrb_customer.name, yrb_customer.city
ORDER BY clubCount
```

Also, if the tuple (`yrb_customer.name`, `yrb_customer.city`) is unique (or is supposed to be - are you counting all students with the same name as the same person?), you might get better performance out of the following:

```
SELECT yrb_customer.name, yrb_customer.city,
       COALESCE(club.count, 0)
FROM yrb_customer
LEFT JOIN (SELECT cid, COUNT(*) as count
           FROM yrb_member
           WHERE club LIKE '%Club%
           GROUP BY cid) club
       ON club.cid = yrb_customer.cid
ORDER BY club.count
```

---

The reason that your original results were being hidden was because in your original query, you have an implicit inner join, which of course requires matching rows.  The implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) is great for inner (regular) joins, but is *terrible* for left-joins, which is what you really needed.  The use of the implicit-join syntax (and certain types of related filtering in the `WHERE` clause) is considered deprecated.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, But I needed to remove the Order By clubCount to get the exact answer I needed

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with DB2 so I'm taking a stab in the dark, but try this:

```
select  yrb_customer.name, 
        yrb_customer.city, 
        CASE WHEN yrb_member.club like '%Club% THEN count(*) ELSE 0 END as #UniClubs 
from  yrb_member, yrb_customer 
where yrb_member.cid = yrb_customer.cid
group by yrb_customer.name, yrb_customer.city  order by count(*)
```

Basically you don't want to filter for %Club% in your WHERE clause because you want ALL rows to come back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but his answer was exactly what I needed. Upvoted you.